# Android - Need help in getting a trigger when WiFi is on and internet is lost

Tags: android

I am a new bee in Android. I am trying to find if there is any way of getting notified (like broadcast receiver for connection status changed) when WiFi is in connected state and Internet connection is lost.

I tried using CONNECTION_CHANGED in manifest file for my receiver. It could not identify if internet connection is lost though WiFi is connected.

I need it to happen in background so that I can login to our service providers page to access internet.

Please help me on how I can get it done.

EDIT: My receiver (registered in manifest for connection changed) is not getting called when internet connection is lost though WiFi is still in connected state. I don't want to start an activity. Instead, I would like to run in background (Asynchtask) when I get this notification.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do u want to trigger for network status that "Internet is available" or u want to get the status for WiFi and network change?

Comment: I want a trigger whenever internet connection is lost to perfirm a login task in our ISP page. WiFi is still connected.

Comment: I just answered the question with broadcast receiver, check it out. It works for me very well.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

This will return

`true`  if wi-fi/mobile data is connected and the internet connection is active.

`false` if wi-fi/mobile data is connected but no internet access.

`false` if wi-fi & mobile data isn't connected at all.

In order to get notified when Internet connection gets lost, One approach I can suggest is to start a service that runs isNetworkAvailable() method I wrote above. You can run it every second(or 5 seconds would be ok) and when it returns false call a custom BroadcastReceiver and on 'onReceive' of that BroadcastReceiver you can build a Notification. Make sure that you create the notification on the first return of 'false' after 'true(s)

This is maybe not the best way but this won't slow down your app I suppose. Prefer to call it every 5 seconds or more.

Comment: What I need is a notification telling me internet connection is not present. How do I get that in background even if no UI is running?

Comment: @user6825303 One approach I can suggest is to start a service that runs `isNetworkAvailable()` method I answered above. You can run it every second and when it returns false call a custom `BroadcastReceiver` and 'onReceive' of that `BroadcastReceiver` you can build a `Notification`.
Make sure that you create the notification on the first return of 'false' after 'true(s)'.

Comment: I will give it a try, and post if I get something. Thank you. Please let me know, in case, if there exists a better way (without checking continuously on every second).

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for network status:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkUtil {

public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    } 
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
}
```

Broadcast receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

        Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Menifest file:

```
<application  ...>
 ...
    <receiver
        android:name="your_package_name.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  ...
```

Comment: I am trying the same way. It did not help me (not getting notification). I will try with your code. I want the trigger even if my activity/ui is not running. For this reason, I tried to register my receiver in manifest.

Comment: Thanks for spending some time to help me. I am sorry if I have confused you. I have WiFi connected, but internet access is not there due to some reason (may be due to broadband ISP server is down, or need to login to access internet). I need to get notified in this case to perform login in background. Please let me know if you need clarification. Also, I don't see where I can ping you.